TabView not rendering correctly for a MenuBarExtra app
I'm building a macOS Menu Bar app (build target is macOS 14.0) and need a settings window as part of it. I'm seeing rendering issues when I use a TabView in this window even though the same syntax works fine in a regular app.
I define the window as a standalone view in my @main block as follows:
struct xyzApp: App {
   MenuBarExtra {
          MenubarView()
        } label: {
          Label("XYZ", image: "xyz")
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
     
        Window("Settings", id: "settings-window") {
            SettingsView()
        }.windowResizability(.contentSize)
}

The Settings view looks like this:
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Form {
                
            }.tabItem { Label("Tab1",systemImage: "gear") }
            Form {
                
            }.tabItem { Label("Tab2",systemImage: "gear") }
        }
        
    }
}

However the TabView is not being rendered correctly, there's no image and the sizing is wrong
bad tabs
I tested the same code on a regular app with a Settings() declaration in the @main block and it works fine. Any points on what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful.

Ok figured it out. It turns out that macos only supports TabView on Settings windows! I worked around this by using SettingsLink to open the Settings window after defining it as follows in my @main block
Settings { SettingsView() }
This is a pretty irritating limitation, hopefully it gets fixed in future releases.
There's a good discussion on SettingsLink here
